NBD Server config directory with multiple files
I'm having trouble getting multiple configs to work on my NBD server.
Scenario 1
This works fine...
/etc/nbd-server/config :
[generic]
  user = nbd 
  group = nbd 
[export]
  exportfile = /path/to/export/file

Scenario 2
But, I need this to work...
/etc/nbd-server/config :
[generic]
  user = nbd 
  group = nbd 
  includedir = /etc/nbd-server/conf.d

So, I should be able to put files in /etc/nbd-server/conf.d/, with...
/etc/nbd-server/conf.d/somefile :
[export]
  exportfile = /path/to/export/file

But, it doesn't.
It only works with everything in the original config (Scenario 1). How can I make Scenario 2 work?

According to the documentation:

includedir
Optional; string
The argument should be a directory containing files with the '.conf'
extension; these files will be parsed as if they were part of the configuration
file. Note that these extra configuration files cannot contain a [generic]
section; any configuration that  should go in the generic section must be
placed in the main configuration file.

That means instead of:
/etc/nbd-server/conf.d/somefile

You need:
/etc/nbd-server/conf.d/somefile.conf

